# How do interpret a part of the dynlm function in R?

Tags: r

In the dynlm package it says:

> Dynamic models: An example would be `d(y) ~ L(y, 2)`, where `d(x, k)` is `diff(x, lag = k)` 
>   and `L(x, k)` is `lag(x, lag = -k)`, note the difference in sign. The default for `k` is in both cases  `1`. For `L()`, it can also be vector-valued, e.g., `y ~ L(y, 1:4)`.

What is meant by "vector-valued"?  In other words, if it were `y ~ L(y, 12:18)`, would this mean it "skips" or "removes" the first 12 lags, and then takes 18 lags from 12 on?

If anyone can answer I would greatly appreciate it!

**EDIT.**
If it means that `y ~ L(y, 12:18)` is equivalent to `lag(y, -(12:18))` then it is not since the following, adapted from the help page `?lag` gives an error.

```
lag(ldeaths, -(12:18))
```

> Error in attr(x, "tsp") <- value :    'tsp' attribute must be numeric
>   of length three
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In if (k != round(k)) { :
>   the condition has length > 1 and only the first
>   element will be used
>   2: In (k/p[3L]) * c(1, 1, 0) :
>   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
>   3: In p - (k/p[3L]) * c(1, 1, 0) :
>   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: Most likely 'vector-valued' just means it's not returning a scalar (single number) and the variable itself and function is returning vectors and not single values.

Comment: The question was further clarified by giving an example where the help page of the problem function fails.

Comment: Quoted error message formated.