# R lag doesn't work inside a loop with counter variable?

Tags: r, lag

This works outside of a loop

```
> past=lag(zoo(c(new$SPCS20RSA)), c(-1,-2,-3,-4,-5), na.pad =TRUE)
> print(past)
       lag-1    lag-2    lag-3    lag-4    lag-5
1         NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
2   169.5526       NA       NA       NA       NA
3   169.5526 169.5526       NA       NA       NA
```

I want to replace new$SPCS20RSA with new[i] (or [a])

I if I run lag inside a loop trying to utilize a counter, I receive an error.
error:

```
for (i in 1:10)
{
  #doesn't work in a loop
  past = lag(c(new[i]), c(-1,-2, -3, -4, -5), na.pad =TRUE)
  print(past)
}
```

> Error in attr(x, "tsp") <- value :    'tsp' attribute must be numeric
>   of length three In addition: Warning messages: 1: In if (k !=
>   round(k)) { :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first
>   element will be used 2: In (k/p[3L]) * c(1, 1, 0) :   longer object
>   length is not a multiple of shorter object length 3: In p - (k/p[3L])
>   * c(1, 1, 0) :   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

If I try [,i]

```
Error in new[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

contents of new as requested

```
> str(new)

List of 79
 $ date            : Date[1:516], format: "2008-01-01" "2008-04-01" "2008-05-04" ...
 $ CPIAUCSL        : num [1:516] 215 215 215 216 216 ...
 $ UNRATE          : num [1:516] 5.4 5.4 5.4 5.45 5.5 5.55 5.6 5.64 5.68 5.72 ...
 $ MEHOINUSA672N   : num [1:516] 56076 55979 55944 55936 55929 ...
 $ INTDSRUSM193N   : num [1:516] 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 2.25 ...
 $ CIVPART         : num [1:516] 66.1 66.1 66.1 66.1 66.1 66.1 66.1 66.1 66.1 66.1 ...
 $ LFWA64TTUSM647S : num [1:516] 1.96e+08 1.96e+08 1.96e+08 1.96e+08 1.96e+08 ...
 $ FEDFUNDS        : num [1:516] 1.98 1.98 1.98 1.98 1.99 ...
 $ GDPC1           : num [1:516] 14963 14963 14939 14933 14928 ...
 $ A191RL1Q225SBEA : num [1:516] 2 2 0.6594 0.375 0.0906 ...
 $ SP500           : num [1:516] 1412 1412 1412 1401 1413 ...
 $ DCOILWTICO      : num [1:516] 114 114 114 123 125 ...
 $ CSUSHPINSA      : num [1:516] 167 167 167 167 167 ...
 $ DFF             : num [1:516] 1.95 1.95 1.95 1.95 1.94 ...
 $ DFII10          : num [1:516] 1.52 1.52 1.52 1.48 1.44 ...
 $ A939RX0Q048SBEA : num [1:516] 49196 49196 49074 49048 49022 ...
 $ PCEPILFE        : num [1:516] 98.7 98.7 98.7 98.8 98.8 ...
 $ GDPDEF          : num [1:516] 99 99 99.2 99.3 99.3 ...
 $ SPCS20RSA       : num [1:516] 170 170 170 169 168 ...
 $ GDPPOT          : num [1:516] 15068 15068 15090 15094 15099 ...
 $ CPILFESL        : num [1:516] 215 215 215 215 215 ...
 $ GOLDAMGBD228NLBM: num [1:516] 859 859 859 878 875 ...
 $ CPIAUCNS        : num [1:516] 217 217 217 217 218 ...
 $ VIXCLS          : num [1:516] 18.5 18.5 18.5 19.1 17.2 ...
 $ WPU0911         : num [1:516] 171 171 171 171 172 ...
 $ PCEPI           : num [1:516] 100 100 100 100 100 ...
 $ USSTHPI         : num [1:516] 361 361 357 356 355 ...
 $ DSPIC96         : num [1:516] 11432 11432 11432 11356 11281 ...
 $ DCOILBRENTEU    : num [1:516] 110 110 110 120 123 ...
 $ FPCPITOTLZGUSA  : num [1:516] 3.84 2.8 2.43 2.35 2.27 ...
 $ PCEC96          : num [1:516] 10084 10084 10084 10081 10077 ...
 $ PPIACO          : num [1:516] 197 197 197 198 199 ...
 $ MEPAINUSA672N   : num [1:516] 29556 29477 29448 29442 29436 ...
 $ GDPCA           : num [1:516] 14830 14729 14692 14684 14676 ...
 $ MPRIME          : num [1:516] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ PAYEMS          : num [1:516] 137870 137870 137870 137832 137793 ...
 $ CES0500000003   : num [1:516] 21.5 21.5 21.5 21.5 21.5 ...
 $ RECPROUSM156N   : num [1:516] 78.2 78.2 78.2 79.7 81.2 ...
 $ IC4WSA          : num [1:516] 363500 363500 363500 363750 368250 ...
 $ AHETPI          : num [1:516] 18 18 18 18 18 ...
 $ M2V             : num [1:516] 1.92 1.92 1.92 1.92 1.91 ...
 $ INDPRO          : num [1:516] 103 103 103 103 103 ...
 $ PCE             : num [1:516] 10093 10093 10093 10107 10121 ...
 $ UMCSENT         : num [1:516] 59.8 59.8 59.8 58.9 58.1 ...
 $ HDTGPDUSQ163N   : num [1:516] 97.7 97.7 98 98.1 98.1 ...
 $ M1V             : num [1:516] 10.6 10.6 10.5 10.5 10.5 ...
 $ TCU             : num [1:516] 79.6 79.6 79.6 79.6 79.5 ...
 $ STLFSI          : num [1:516] 0.99 0.99 0.99 0.757 0.653 0.585 0.667 0.743 0.889 0.886 ...
 $ BASE            : num [1:516] 857 857 857 857 859 ...
 $ PSAVERT         : num [1:516] 7.9 7.9 7.9 7.3 6.7 6.1 5.5 5.28 5.06 4.84 ...
 $ M2              : num [1:516] 7673 7673 7673 7673 7688 ...
 $ M1              : num [1:516] 1394 1394 1394 1394 1393 ...
 $ M1SL            : num [1:516] 1394 1394 1394 1396 1398 ...
 $ M2SL            : num [1:516] 7696 7696 7696 7701 7705 ...
 $ T10Y2Y          : num [1:516] 1.42 1.42 1.42 1.53 1.41 ...
 $ DGS10           : num [1:516] 3.83 3.83 3.83 3.85 3.86 ...
 $ BAMLH0A0HYM2    : num [1:516] 6.72 6.72 6.72 6.76 6.73 ...
 $ TB3MS           : num [1:516] 1.73 1.73 1.73 1.76 1.79 ...
 $ T10YIE          : num [1:516] 2.31 2.31 2.31 2.37 2.41 ...
 $ TEDRATE         : num [1:516] 1.33 1.33 1.33 1.09 0.91 ...
 $ GFDEGDQ188S     : num [1:516] 64.1 64.1 65.3 65.5 65.8 ...
 $ T5YIFR          : num [1:516] 2.33 2.33 2.33 2.43 2.48 ...
 $ T10Y3M          : num [1:516] 2.36 2.36 2.36 2.21 2.04 ...
 $ DGS1            : num [1:516] 1.96 1.96 1.96 1.94 2.07 ...
 $ USSLIND         : num [1:516] 0.02 0.02 0.02 -0.01 -0.04 -0.07 -0.1 -0.162 -0.224 -0.286 ...
 $ BAMLC0A4CBBB    : num [1:516] 2.98 2.98 2.98 2.96 2.94 ...
 $ GFDEBTN         : num [1:516] 9492006 9492006 9675128 9713972 9752816 ...
 $ DGS2            : num [1:516] 2.42 2.42 2.42 2.32 2.44 ...
 $ GS10            : num [1:516] 3.88 3.88 3.88 3.93 3.99 ...
 $ DGS5            : num [1:516] 3.12 3.12 3.12 3.07 3.12 ...
 $ DGS30           : num [1:516] 4.53 4.53 4.53 4.57 4.58 ...
 $ TREAST          : num [1:516] 536714 536714 536714 536714 515656 ...
 $ BAA10Y          : num [1:516] 3 3 3 3.04 3.06 ...
 $ BAMLC0A0CM      : num [1:516] 2.55 2.55 2.55 2.52 2.51 ...
 $ BAMLH0A3HYC     : num [1:516] 10.6 10.6 10.6 10.6 10.6 ...
 $ FYFSD           : num [1:516] -458553 -458553 -458553 -458553 -458553 ...
 $ DGS1MO          : num [1:516] 1.24 1.24 1.24 1.52 1.83 ...
 $ T5YIE           : num [1:516] 2.29 2.29 2.29 2.3 2.34 ...
 $ FutureSPCS20RSA : num 170

> new <- head(new)
> print(new)

$`date`
  [1] "2008-01-01" "2008-04-01" "2008-05-04" "2008-05-11" "2008-05-18" "2008-05-25" "2008-06-01" "2008-06-08"
  [9] "2008-06-15" "2008-06-22" "2008-06-29" "2008-07-06" "2008-07-13" "2008-07-20" "2008-07-27" "2008-08-03"
 [17] "2008-08-10" "2008-08-17" "2008-08-24" "2008-08-31" "2008-09-07" "2008-09-14" "2008-09-21" "2008-09-28"
 [25] "2008-10-05" "2008-10-12" "2008-10-19" "2008-10-26" "2008-11-02" "2008-11-09" "2008-11-16" "2008-11-23"
 [33] "2008-11-30" "2008-12-07" "2008-12-14" "2008-12-21" "2008-12-28" "2009-01-04" "2009-01-11" "2009-01-18"
 [41] "2009-01-25" "2009-02-01" "2009-02-08" "2009-02-15" "2009-02-22" "2009-03-01" "2009-03-08" "2009-03-15"
 [49] "2009-03-22" "2009-03-29" "2009-04-05" "2009-04-12" "2009-04-19" "2009-04-26" "2009-05-03" "2009-05-10"
 [57] "2009-05-17" "2009-05-24" "2009-05-31" "2009-06-07" "2009-06-14" "2009-06-21" "2009-06-28" "2009-07-05"
 [65] "2009-07-12" "2009-07-19" "2009-07-26" "2009-08-02" "2009-08-09" "2009-08-16" "2009-08-23" "2009-08-30"
 [73] "2009-09-06" "2009-09-13" "2009-09-20" "2009-09-27" "2009-10-04" "2009-10-11" "2009-10-18" "2009-10-25"
 [81] "2009-11-01" "2009-11-08" "2009-11-15" "2009-11-22" "2009-11-29" "2009-12-06" "2009-12-13" "2009-12-20"
 [89] "2009-12-27" "2010-01-03" "2010-01-10" "2010-01-17" "2010-01-24" "2010-01-31" "2010-02-07" "2010-02-14"
 [97] "2010-02-21" "2010-02-28" "2010-03-07" "2010-03-14" "2010-03-21" "2010-03-28" "2010-04-04" "2010-04-11"
[105] "2010-04-18" "2010-04-25" "2010-05-02" "2010-05-09" "2010-05-16" "2010-05-23" "2010-05-30" "2010-06-06"
[113] "2010-06-13" "2010-06-20" "2010-06-27" "2010-07-04" "2010-07-11" "2010-07-18" "2010-07-25" "2010-08-01"
[121] "2010-08-08" "2010-08-15" "2010-08-22" "2010-08-29" "2010-09-05" "2010-09-12" "2010-09-19" "2010-09-26"
[129] "2010-10-03" "2010-10-10" "2010-10-17" "2010-10-24" "2010-10-31" "2010-11-07" "2010-11-14" "2010-11-21"
[137] "2010-11-28" "2010-12-05" "2010-12-12" "2010-12-19" "2010-12-26" "2011-01-02" "2011-01-09" "2011-01-16"
[145] "2011-01-23" "2011-01-30" "2011-02-06" "2011-02-13" "2011-02-20" "2011-02-27" "2011-03-06" "2011-03-13"
[153] "2011-03-20" "2011-03-27" "2011-04-03" "2011-04-10" "2011-04-17" "2011-04-24" "2011-05-01" "2011-05-08"
[161] "2011-05-15" "2011-05-22" "2011-05-29" "2011-06-05" "2011-06-12" "2011-06-19" "2011-06-26" "2011-07-03"
[169] "2011-07-10" "2011-07-17" "2011-07-24" "2011-07-31" "2011-08-07" "2011-08-14" "2011-08-21" "2011-08-28"
[177] "2011-09-04" "2011-09-11" "2011-09-18" "2011-09-25" "2011-10-02" "2011-10-09" "2011-10-16" "2011-10-23"
[185] "2011-10-30" "2011-11-06" "2011-11-13" "2011-11-20" "2011-11-27" "2011-12-04" "2011-12-11" "2011-12-18"
[193] "2011-12-25" "2012-01-01" "2012-01-08" "2012-01-15" "2012-01-22" "2012-01-29" "2012-02-05" "2012-02-12"
[201] "2012-02-19" "2012-02-26" "2012-03-04" "2012-03-11" "2012-03-18" "2012-03-25" "2012-04-01" "2012-04-08"
[209] "2012-04-15" "2012-04-22" "2012-04-29" "2012-05-06" "2012-05-13" "2012-05-20" "2012-05-27" "2012-06-03"
[217] "2012-06-10" "2012-06-17" "2012-06-24" "2012-07-01" "2012-07-08" "2012-07-15" "2012-07-22" "2012-07-29"
[225] "2012-08-05" "2012-08-12" "2012-08-19" "2012-08-26" "2012-09-02" "2012-09-09" "2012-09-16" "2012-09-23"
[233] "2012-09-30" "2012-10-07" "2012-10-14" "2012-10-21" "2012-10-28" "2012-11-04" "2012-11-11" "2012-11-18"
[241] "2012-11-25" "2012-12-02" "2012-12-09" "2012-12-16" "2012-12-23" "2012-12-30" "2013-01-06" "2013-01-13"
[249] "2013-01-20" "2013-01-27" "2013-02-03" "2013-02-10" "2013-02-17" "2013-02-24" "2013-03-03" "2013-03-10"
[257] "2013-03-17" "2013-03-24" "2013-03-31" "2013-04-07" "2013-04-14" "2013-04-21" "2013-04-28" "2013-05-05"
[265] "2013-05-12" "2013-05-19" "2013-05-26" "2013-06-02" "2013-06-09" "2013-06-16" "2013-06-23" "2013-06-30"
[273] "2013-07-07" "2013-07-14" "2013-07-21" "2013-07-28" "2013-08-04" "2013-08-11" "2013-08-18" "2013-08-25"
[281] "2013-09-01" "2013-09-08" "2013-09-15" "2013-09-22" "2013-09-29" "2013-10-06" "2013-10-13" "2013-10-20"
[289] "2013-10-27" "2013-11-03" "2013-11-10" "2013-11-17" "2013-11-24" "2013-12-01" "2013-12-08" "2013-12-15"
[297] "2013-12-22" "2013-12-29" "2014-01-05" "2014-01-12" "2014-01-19" "2014-01-26" "2014-02-02" "2014-02-09"
[305] "2014-02-16" "2014-02-23" "2014-03-02" "2014-03-09" "2014-03-16" "2014-03-23" "2014-03-30" "2014-04-06"
[313] "2014-04-13" "2014-04-20" "2014-04-27" "2014-05-04" "2014-05-11" "2014-05-18" "2014-05-25" "2014-06-01"
[321] "2014-06-08" "2014-06-15" "2014-06-22" "2014-06-29" "2014-07-06" "2014-07-13" "2014-07-20" "2014-07-27"
[329] "2014-08-03" "2014-08-10" "2014-08-17" "2014-08-24" "2014-08-31" "2014-09-07" "2014-09-14" "2014-09-21"
[337] "2014-09-28" "2014-10-05" "2014-10-12" "2014-10-19" "2014-10-26" "2014-11-02" "2014-11-09" "2014-11-16"
[345] "2014-11-23" "2014-11-30" "2014-12-07" "2014-12-14" "2014-12-21" "2014-12-28" "2015-01-04" "2015-01-11"
[353] "2015-01-18" "2015-01-25" "2015-02-01" "2015-02-08" "2015-02-15" "2015-02-22" "2015-03-01" "2015-03-08"
[361] "2015-03-15" "2015-03-22" "2015-03-29" "2015-04-05" "2015-04-12" "2015-04-19" "2015-04-26" "2015-05-03"
[369] "2015-05-10" "2015-05-17" "2015-05-24" "2015-05-31" "2015-06-07" "2015-06-14" "2015-06-21" "2015-06-28"
[377] "2015-07-05" "2015-07-12" "2015-07-19" "2015-07-26" "2015-08-02" "2015-08-09" "2015-08-16" "2015-08-23"
[385] "2015-08-30" "2015-09-06" "2015-09-13" "2015-09-20" "2015-09-27" "2015-10-04" "2015-10-11" "2015-10-18"
[393] "2015-10-25" "2015-11-01" "2015-11-08" "2015-11-15" "2015-11-22" "2015-11-29" "2015-12-06" "2015-12-13"
[401] "2015-12-20" "2015-12-27" "2016-01-03" "2016-01-10" "2016-01-17" "2016-01-24" "2016-01-31" "2016-02-07"
[409] "2016-02-14" "2016-02-21" "2016-02-28" "2016-03-06" "2016-03-13" "2016-03-20" "2016-03-27" "2016-04-03"
[417] "2016-04-10" "2016-04-17" "2016-04-24" "2016-05-01" "2016-05-08" "2016-05-15" "2016-05-22" "2016-05-29"
[425] "2016-06-05" "2016-06-12" "2016-06-19" "2016-06-26" "2016-07-03" "2016-07-10" "2016-07-17" "2016-07-24"
[433] "2016-07-31" "2016-08-07" "2016-08-14" "2016-08-21" "2016-08-28" "2016-09-04" "2016-09-11" "2016-09-18"
[441] "2016-09-25" "2016-10-02" "2016-10-09" "2016-10-16" "2016-10-23" "2016-10-30" "2016-11-06" "2016-11-13"
[449] "2016-11-20" "2016-11-27" "2016-12-04" "2016-12-11" "2016-12-18" "2016-12-25" "2017-01-01" "2017-01-08"
[457] "2017-01-15" "2017-01-22" "2017-01-29" "2017-02-05" "2017-02-12" "2017-02-19" "2017-02-26" "2017-03-05"
[465] "2017-03-12" "2017-03-19" "2017-03-26" "2017-04-02" "2017-04-09" "2017-04-16" "2017-04-23" "2017-04-30"
[473] "2017-05-07" "2017-05-14" "2017-05-21" "2017-05-28" "2017-06-04" "2017-06-11" "2017-06-18" "2017-06-25"
[481] "2017-07-02" "2017-07-09" "2017-07-16" "2017-07-23" "2017-07-30" "2017-08-06" "2017-08-13" "2017-08-20"
[489] "2017-08-27" "2017-09-03" "2017-09-10" "2017-09-17" "2017-09-24" "2017-10-01" "2017-10-08" "2017-10-15"
[497] "2017-10-22" "2017-10-29" "2017-11-05" "2017-11-12" "2017-11-19" "2017-11-26" "2017-12-03" "2017-12-10"
[505] "2017-12-17" "2017-12-24" "2017-12-31" "2018-01-07" "2018-01-14" "2018-01-21" "2018-01-28" "2018-02-04"
[513] "2018-02-11" "2018-02-18" "2018-02-25" "2018-03-01"

$CPIAUCSL
  [1] 215.2080 215.2080 215.2080 215.7717 216.3355 216.8992 217.4630 217.7736 218.0842 218.3948 218.7054
 [12] 219.0160 218.9345 218.8530 218.7715 218.6900 218.7274 218.7648 218.8022 218.8396 218.8770 218.4065
 [23] 217.9360 217.4655 216.9950 216.0345 215.0740 214.1135 213.1530 212.8020 212.4510 212.1000 211.7490
 [34] 211.3980 211.5317 211.6655 211.7993 211.9330 212.1260 212.3190 212.5120 212.7050 212.6525 212.6000
 [45] 212.5475 212.4950 212.5378 212.5806 212.6234 212.6662 212.7090 212.7873 212.8655 212.9437 213.0220
 [56] 213.3756 213.7292 214.0828 214.4364 214.7900 214.7740 214.7580 214.7420 214.7260 214.9058 215.0855
 [67] 215.2652 215.4450 215.5282 215.6114 215.6946 215.7778 215.8610 216.0230 216.1850 216.3470 216.5090
 [78] 216.6902 216.8715 217.0528 217.2340 217.2566 217.2792 217.3018 217.3244 217.3470 217.3822 217.4175
 [89] 217.4528 217.4880 217.4466 217.4052 217.3638 217.3224 217.2810 217.2990 217.3170 217.3350 217.3530
```

Solution

```
for (i in parsedList)
{

  past = lag(zoo(c(new[[i]])), c(-1,-2, -3, -4, -5), na.pad =TRUE)

  print(temp)

}
```

Comment: I don't understand your `for` loop; you're not using `i` anywhere inside the loop. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Ronak Shah, I have , care to link any?

Answer (score 1):

The `Error: unexpected '}' in "}"` error comes from a syntax error. You have one superfluous opening parenthesis in front of `c()`

```
a=1
for (i in parsedList)
{
  #doesn't work in a loop
  past = lag(c(new[a]), c(-1,-2, -3, -4, -5), na.pad =TRUE)
  a=a+1
}
```

I hope you defined 'new' before, else you get error:
Error in new[a] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
(because it is a function used for object oriented programming, to create new objects).

Comment: new error: Error in attr(x, "tsp") <- value : 
  'tsp' attribute must be numeric of length three
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (k != round(k)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In (k/p[3L]) * c(1, 1, 0) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In p - (k/p[3L]) * c(1, 1, 0) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: I see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498460/how-do-interpret-a-part-of-the-dynlm-function-in-r

Comment: you have to show a minimal working example - because we don't have variable definitions and functions you wrote before. so the code snippet you provided is not runnable for us.

Comment: I added an example

Comment: how about giving a working minimal example of parsedList with just 3 elements or so?

Comment: If parsedList is really a list, then you have to give `new[[a]]` if you want equivalent subsetting like with new$something.

Comment: still throwing the same error when I try for (i in 1:10) or for (i in parsedList); and then try past = lag(c(new[[i]]), c(-1,-2, -3, -4, -5), na.pad =TRUE)

Comment: what is actually `new`? - still not a working minimal example provided ...

Comment: new is a dataframe with 77 columns

Comment: then it has to be new[, i] because these are columns. You can save us helpers a lot of time if you from beginning on create a small working minimal example. I would have seen it immediately, if I would have known that .

Comment: Error in new[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions.  I'm confused by what you mean a minimum working example.  As I can't get the code to work.  I suppose you wish to see the dataframe defined.

Comment: show me new, please ... maybe new is not a dataframe ... can be sth similar to a data frame - or maybe it is an object ... which is subsettable using `$` ... Do str(new) ... and place as minimal example new <- head(new)

Comment: True. Minimum working example fulfilling all needs - the necessary informations there to fix the problem. Mostly objects in miniature (like only first 3 elements of a list, or the first n lines of a data frame given the name - you use in the code) so that one can tinker around with it.

Comment: ah, you see str(new) shows that new is actually a list!

Comment: in this case, new[[i]] is correct, and you forgot zoo() around c(new[[i]])

Comment: and problem in the list 'new' is that the first element is in date format and not numeric like all the others. maybe you have to leave the first element out.  so put `a <- 2` at the beginning! Then, it has good chance to run through!  - and you see,how important str() is. Because it shows you the types of the elements inside objects and of the objects and which classes they belong too etc. Thinking in types is so important for programming ...

Comment: thank you!  I did find this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055927/how-can-i-automatically-create-n-lags-in-a-timeseries Your solution worked with the zoo... :)

Comment: please upvote me then - for the effort ;) - welcome!